# How to print the hands of a clock by calling a function using the setInterval method

Tags: javascript, canvas, setinterval

I'm trying to print the hand of a clock that I have drawn in canvas by using the `setInterval()` method in Javascript.

What I want to happen is that the hand points to 12 initially. The `setInterval()` method should run every 3 seconds and will rotate by the hand by 30 degrees. This will result in the hand being redrawn pointing at 1, followed by it being redrawn pointing at 2 in 3 more seconds, and so on and so forth.

I have tried writing the function within the setInterval() method, but I am confused about the order of operations.

```js
let canvas = window.document.getElementById("myCanvas");
let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");


function setup() {
  drawCircle();
  drawNumbers();
  setInterval(function() {
    ctx.translate(250, 250);
    ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
    ctx.lineTo(0, -100);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.rotate(30 * Math.PI / 180)
    ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
    ctx.lineTo(0, -100);
    ctx.stroke();
  }, 3000);
}

function drawCircle() {
  ctx.save();
  ctx.translate(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2);
  ctx.arc(0, 0, 200, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.restore();
}

function drawNumbers() {
  ctx.save();
  ctx.translate(canvas.width / 2, canvas.width / 2);
  for (let i = 12; i >= 1; i--) {
    ctx.strokeText(i, -5, -185);
    ctx.rotate(-30 * Math.PI / 180);
  }
  ctx.restore();
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Analogue Clock</title>
  <script src='script.js' defer></script>
</head>

<body onload="setup()">
  <canvas id="myCanvas" width="500" height="500" style="border: 1px solid black"></canvas>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Some advice I can give you when debugging graphics/simulation issues: 1. Break the code up into two parts - the part that's _not_ changing during your interval, and the part that _is_ changing. Once you have this set up, you can disable each piece individually to determine which piece is causing issues. In this case, I would break your `setup` function into two other functions: `setupClock()` which sets up the clock boundary (`drawCircle()`) and the numbers, and then `drawHands()`, which draws the hands of the clock.

Comment: Also, this might be useful to other users: https://jsfiddle.net/0qba7yec/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your code I can see you can draw the clock just fine...

You are just having a bit of troubles with the movement/animation of the hands, one thing you are missing is to clear the canvas before you draw again, otherwise you will get the same hand drawn multiple times, below is an animated version of your code.

Now the hand is not moving at the frequency you requested, I leave that for you to figure out.

```js
let canvas = window.document.getElementById("myCanvas");
let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
let increment = 0

function drawNumbers() {
  ctx.save();
  ctx.translate(canvas.width / 2, canvas.width / 2);
  for (let i = 12; i >= 1; i--) {    
    ctx.strokeText(i, -5, canvas.width / 8 - canvas.width / 2);
    ctx.rotate(-30 * Math.PI / 180);
  }
  ctx.restore();
}

function drawTicks() {
  ctx.save();
  ctx.translate(canvas.width / 2, canvas.width / 2);
  ctx.rotate(increment * Math.PI / 180)
  ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
  ctx.lineTo(0, canvas.width / 6 - canvas.width / 2);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.restore();
}

function draw() {
  increment++;
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.width);
  ctx.beginPath();
  drawNumbers();
  drawTicks();
}

draw();
setInterval(draw, 100);
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="250" height="250" ></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're always rotating by 30 degrees, every iteration: `ctx.rotate(30 * Math.PI / 180)`.

What you actually need to do is keep track of which iteration of the `setInterval()` method you're on (i.e. how many times it's been called), so that you can multiply this by the number of degrees you want to rotate.

In other words, you're *always* rotating by 30 degrees, but what you *want* to do is rotate by 30 degrees *times* the number of iterations you've already executed.

Comment: One other thing you should keep in mind - you're not clearing the context per draw. Each frame in the animation (i.e. each call to `setInterval()`) should clear the context, draw the bounds of the clock, and then draw the hands of the clock. Otherwise, you'll have leftover pieces of previous frames when you're trying to draw the updated hands.